# Cholesky decomposition of a positive semi-deﬁnite

Tags: matrix-theory

We know that  a positive deﬁnite matrix has a  Cholesky decomposition,but I want to know how a Cholesky decomposition can be done for positive semi-deﬁnite matrices?The following sentences come from a paper.
"There are two assumptions on the speciﬁed correlation matrix R. The ﬁrst is a general assumption that R is a possible correlation matrix, i.e. that it is a symmetric positive semideﬁnite matrix with 1’s on the main diagonal. While implementing the algorithm there is no need to check positive semi-deﬁniteness directly, as we do a Cholesky decomposition of the matrix R at the very start. If R is not positive semi-deﬁnite, the Cholesky decomposition will fail."
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: THANK YOU .but here I want to know if a positive semi-deﬁnite can be done for   Cholesky decomposition? and how?

Comment: "that how a positive semi-deﬁnite be done for Cholesky decomposition"??? What do you mean?

Comment: excuse for my bad english."There are two assumptions on the speciﬁed correlation matrix R. The ﬁrst is a general assumption that R is a possible correlation matrix, i.e. that it is a symmetric positive semideﬁnite matrix with 1’s on the main diagonal. While implementing the algorithm there is no need to check positive semi-deﬁniteness directly, as we do a Cholesky decomposition of the matrix R at the very start. If R is not positive semi-deﬁnite, the Cholesky decomposition will fail."

Comment: Do you mean to ask why R has a Cholesky decomposition if and only if R is positive semidefinite?

Comment: It is no doubt that R has a Cholesky decomposition when R is a positive definite matrix.I want to ask Whether R has a Cholesky decomposition when R is a positive semi-definite?Thank you for your patience~~

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition has a proof that yes, indeed, it is correct, a p.s.d. R will have a Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.In Matlab Programming, the "chol" command can be used to simply apply this to only a positive definite matrix.When it comes to a positive semi-definite matrix，“chol” fails.I want to ask if there any command in Matlab Programming that can be used to a positive semi-definite matrix?

Comment: how about ldl ?

Answer (score 8):

You can either:

- use a LDL^T decomposition (see e.g. [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/ldl.html))
- deflate the kernel yourself before: that is, compute a basis $Q_2$ for the kernel, complete it to a square orthonormal matrix $Q=[Q_1 \, Q_2]$, and assemble
  $$
  Q^TRQ=\begin{bmatrix}R_{11} & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},
  $$
  where $R_{11}$ is going to be nonsingular (and hence can be Cholesky-factored).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind including some permutations, you can get a variant of Cholesky that still has the rank-revealing property:

$$P^T R P = R_1^T R, \quad R_1 = \begin{bmatrix} R_{11} & R_{22} \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

This is a matter of simple greedy pivoting. For the algorithm and more details, see Higham's "[Cholesky Factorization](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1199/01/covered/MIMS_ep2008_116.pdf)".